# Positioning footnotes before the bibliography

Tags: sectioning, positioning, footnotes

I don't want a separate page for my bibliography, so the references simply follow after the end of the actual document. However, there happens to be a footnote on the last page which is then displayed *underneath* the references. How can I move the footnote to just beneath the text, but before the references?

Screenshot of the last page:
[image]

Comment: Did you already checked the package 'footmisc'? It's a good point to start.

Comment: @Martin Sharrer yup, nothing there. `\skip\footins` doesn't do the trick either.

Comment: One crazy idea would be to put the bibliography in a bottom float, i.e. `{figure}[b]` environment. Then the footnote is placed above it. However this leaves all the white space between text and footnote + bibl.

Comment: @Martin Sharrer this could work by putting the text into a minipage. The footnote then appears just beneath it, although it doesn't feel like a satisfactory solution, somehow..

Comment: @mewoshh: Note the letter "c" in Martin Scharrer's name `:-)`

Comment: @newoshh: A even better and more crazier idea: Place the bibliography as footnote! E.g. using `{\def\thefootnote{}\footnotetext{\normalsize YOURBIB}}`. This should place it direct below the last footnote without any footnote number. The funny thing is that `\raggedbottom` doesn't place the footnotes direct under the text in my LaTeX installation. All sources I found so far tell me it should. @Hendrik: Thanks!

Comment: @Martin Sorry for the typo! Anyway, I put the text of the last page in a minipage (required some adjustments to the footnote counter) and put the bibliography into a figure[h]. Works just fine, but thanks for your second crazy idea as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods that work are:

- Put the text from the last page into a `minipage` and enclose the bibliography with `{figure}[h]`. Adjust the footnote counters in the minipage by setting your own minipage counter.
- Or as Martin Scharrer suggested, place the bibliography as footnote, e.g. using `{\def\thefootnote{}\footnotetext{\normalsize YOURBIB}}`.

Answer (score 2):

While I appreciate the solutions of Martin and Milosz, my advice is: Don't do it. Your bibliography is basically formatted as a normal section (save the numbering), and footnotes should always be placed at the bottom of a page, even when they are part of section "X" and a new section "X+1" starts in the middle of the page. (Milosz: Your screenshot shows footnote no. 4 -- I wonder what the pages with footnotes no. 1--3 look like.) If you really abhor footnotes after section-bibliographies, consider switching to endnotes for the whole document (these notes may be placed in a separate section before the bibliography).

If you insist on positioning a footnote in the middle of a page and use a minipage environment for the text on the last page to do so, pay attention to the formatting of any "paragraph" that spans both the penultimate and the last page -- e.g., make sure that the last line on the penultimate page is justified.